# I am trying to build a variational autoencoder. I am getting an error while running model.fit which I don't understand

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-f82b6d9aa841> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Train model
----> 2 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=16, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

TypeError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 317, in __call__
        self._total_loss_mean.update_state(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 77, in decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/metrics/base_metric.py", line 140, in update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/metrics/base_metric.py", line 477, in update_state  **
        sample_weight = tf.__internal__.ops.broadcast_weights(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/keras_tensor.py", line 283, in __array__
        raise TypeError(

    TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='Placeholder:0', description="created by layer 'tf.cast_2'"), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.
```

this is the code

```
def load_data4():
    # Set path to directory containing images
    path_to_images = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Heatsource504'

    # Define regular expression pattern to extract coordinates
    pattern = r'x_(\d+)y_(\d+)\.jpg'

    # Initialize empty lists to store image data and corresponding coordinates
    images = []
    heatmaps = []
    coordinates = []

    # Loop through images and extract data and coordinates
    for filename in os.listdir(path_to_images):
        match = re.search(pattern, filename)
        if match:
            x_coord = int(match.group(1))
            y_coord = int(match.group(2))
            img = Image.open(os.path.join(path_to_images, filename))
            img = img.resize((200, 200))  # resize image to desired dimensions
            img_array = np.array(img)  # convert image to numpy array

            # Convert image to grayscale if it is not already grayscale
            if len(img_array.shape) == 3 and img_array.shape[2] == 3:
                img_array = cv2.cvtColor(img_array, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

            # Check if image is of type uint8, and convert it to uint8 if necessary
            if img_array.dtype != 'uint8':
                img_array = img_array.astype('uint8')

            # Normalize pixel values of input image to be between 0 and 1
            img_array = img_array / 255.0

            # Add input image and corresponding output image to lists
            heatmaps.append(img_array)
            images.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_to_images, filename)))
            coordinates.append([x_coord, y_coord])

    # Convert lists to numpy arrays
    images = np.array(images)
    heatmaps = np.array(heatmaps)
    coordinates = np.array(coordinates)

    # Split data into training and validation sets
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val, coords_train, coords_val = train_test_split(heatmaps, images, coordinates, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    return X_train, y_train, coords_train, X_val, y_val, coords_val


input_shape = (200, 200, 1)

# Encoder
inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
x = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(x)

# Define latent variables
latent_dim = 10
mu = Dense(units=latent_dim)(x)
log_var = Dense(units=latent_dim)(x)

# Reparameterization trick
def sampling(args):
    mu, log_var = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=K.shape(mu))
    return mu + K.exp(log_var / 2) * epsilon
# Sample latent variables
z = Lambda(sampling)([mu, log_var])

# Decoder
x = Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(z)
x = Dense(units=8 * 8 * 128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Reshape(target_shape=(8, 8, 128))(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=4, padding='valid', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding='valid', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=16, kernel_size=3, padding='valid', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=2, padding='valid', activation='sigmoid')(x)

# Define VAE loss function
def vae_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    reconstruction_loss = binary_crossentropy(K.flatten(y_true), K.flatten(y_pred))
    reconstruction_loss *= input_shape[0] * input_shape[1] * input_shape[2]
    kl_loss = 1 + log_var - K.square(mu) - K.exp(log_var)
    kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
    kl_loss *= -0.5
    vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
    return vae_loss

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=vae_loss)

# Load data
X_train, y_train, coords_train, X_val, y_val, coords_val = load_data4()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=16, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember this happened to me as well. It seems that tensorflow doesn't support a vae_loss function like this anymore.
I have 2 solutions to this, I will paste here the short and simple one. Instead of creating a vae_loss function, you need to add the loss like this:

```
reconstruction_loss = binary_crossentropy(K.flatten(inputs), K.flatten(outputs)) #I think in your case outputs is x
reconstruction_loss *= input_shape[0] * input_shape[1] * input_shape[2]
kl_loss = 1 + log_var - K.square(mu) - K.exp(log_var)
kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
kl_loss *= -0.5
vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
model.add_loss(vae_loss) #This is the key

model.compile(optimizer='adam')
```

I also have another solution to this problem, that is using a custom model. You can find this solution here:
https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/